# How to display the weekly view in manage availability in rooms_availability?

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I installed the [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) module, and enabled all dependencies. Now when I edit a bookable unit and when I click in "manage availability", I can edit availability per month.

But I do not want a monthly view, I want weekly view. And I want to select the availability per hours/days.

Is that possible? And is there any other way to do this? Or is there another change in the code?

[image]

Comment: Any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to display a weekly view. But as per your "***... is there another change in the code ...***", it seems like it should be pretty forward to transform the 3 months view to a single month view via [rooms_three_month_calendar.tpl.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rooms/tree/rooms_three_month_calendar.tpl.php).

To actually do so, remove line 2 (with `class="month1"`) and line 4 (with `class="month3"`) from this part of that tpl file:

```
<div class="calendar-set clearfix">
  <div id='calendar' class="month1"></div>
  <div id='calendar1' class="month2"></div>
  <div id='calendar2' class="month3"></div>
</div>
```

After doing so, it should look like so:

```
<div class="calendar-set clearfix">
  <div id='calendar1' class="month2"></div>
</div>
```

Still not exactly a weekly view, but at least you already got rid of 2/3 of the days you don't want to see, right? And hence leaves 3 times as much space for the current month view.

**Note**: By not removing the backward / current / forward links in that tpl file, you should still be able to easily navigate to another month.